# Button text disappears when scrolling table

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uibutton

So i embedded two buttons within each table cell in my Uitableview. I allow the user to edit the button title. However as soon as the user scrolls the cell off the screen, the title becomes blank again. Any idea how to fix this? Here is my code:

TableView Method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
  if(cell == nil){
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
  }

  addWeightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  addRepButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  [addWeightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(weightPressedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [addRepButton addTarget:self action:@selector(repPressedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  addWeightButton.frame = CGRectMake(110.0f, 5.0f, 75.0f, 30.0f);
  addRepButton.frame = CGRectMake(260.0f, 5.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
  [addWeightButton setTag:indexPath.row];
  [addRepButton setTag:indexPath.row];
  [cell addSubview:addWeightButton];
  [cell addSubview:addRepButton];
  return cell; 
}
```

Edit Button Title Method

```
-(void) editWeightNumber:(int)value {
  [[routine objectAtIndex:index] addWeight:value atIndex:selectedWeightBox];
  NSString* weights = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [[routine objectAtIndex:index] getWeight:selectedWeightBox]];
  [weightSender setTitle:weights forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 }
```

Comment: I don't see any code that sets the title of the button in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, where you are creating new instances of the buttons. Each time you scroll the cell with buttons off screen, then on again, the buttons are recreated, even though the cells are being reused. You will need to implement the tracking of the button titles for each of the cell along with the collection that holds the other cell data.

Comment: Ahh i see. Managed to figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As commented by bobnoble, you need to also set the titles in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, because this is where you're creating new (or reusing different) instances of the buttons. So
insert before `return cell` something that will fetch and set the edited title. Something along the lines of:

```
id routineObject = [routine objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *weights = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [routineObject getWeight:addWeightBox]];
[addWeightButton setTitle:weights forState:UIControlStateNormal];
NSString *reps = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [routineObject getWeight:addRepBox]];
[addRepButton setTitle:reps forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```